# How to get values from one column corresponding to other

Tags: python, r, dataframe

I have a data frame like this

```
Action Stage
    a1     A
    a2     A
    a3     B
    a4     B
```

I want to get value like, `A=[a1,a2] and  B=[a3,a4]`

How can I do it in R or python?

Answer (score 0):

`R` solution could be

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Stage) %>%
  summarize(Val=paste0("[",paste(Action,collapse = ","),"]")) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(desired_val = paste(Stage, Val, sep = "="))
```

Output is:

```
  Stage     Val desired_val
1     A [a1,a2]   A=[a1,a2]
2     B [a3,a4]   B=[a3,a4]
```

```
#sample data
> dput(df)
structure(list(Action = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"), Stage = c("A", 
"A", "B", "B")), .Names = c("Action", "Stage"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do :

```
split(df$Stage)
```

The value will be split into a list.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

If we use the data object from Prems answer (but name it dfrm to avoid confusion with the function named `df`) and the idea of using `split` from Sofaine (but using the Stage column as the second argument rather than the first) then

```
(sdfrm <- split( dfrm$Action, dfrm$Stage))
$A
[1] "a1" "a2"

$B
[1] "a3" "a4"

> sdfrm$A
[1] "a1" "a2"
```

Answer (score 0):

In R, using your example:

```
Action <- c("a1","a2","a3","a4")
Stage <- c("A","A","B","B")
data <- data.frame(Action, Stage)

> u <- unique(Stage)
> v <- vector()
> for(i in 1:length(u)){
+   v[i] <- paste(data[which(data$Stage == u[i]),"Action"],collapse=",")
+ }
> d <- data.frame(u,v)
> d

  u     v
1 A a1,a2
2 B a3,a4
```